# Django admin: exclude field on change form only

Tags: python, django, django-admin

If there a way to detect if information in a model is being added or changed.

If there is can this information be used to exclude fields.

Some pseudocode to illustrate what I'm talking about.

```
class SubSectionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    if something.change_or_add = 'change':
        exclude = ('field',)
    ...
```

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
class SubSectionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # ...
    def change_view(self, request, object_id, extra_context=None):       
        self.exclude = ('field', )
        return super(SubSectionAdmin, self).change_view(request, object_id, extra_context)
```

Comment: self.exclude = ('field',)

Comment: What if the field is a custom field in admin form?

Comment: See the answers below for why this is dangerous and not the way to go. The Admin objects are singletons so setting self.exclude changes the state of the SubSectionAdmin for subsequent add_view calls.

Answer (score 18):

orwellian's answer will make the whole SubSectionAdmin singleton change its exclude property.

A way to ensure that fields are excluded on a per-request basis is to do something like:

```
class SubSectionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # ...
    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        """Override the get_form and extend the 'exclude' keyword arg"""
        if obj:
            kwargs.update({
                'exclude': getattr(kwargs, 'exclude', tuple()) + ('field',),
            })
        return super(SubSectionAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
```

which will just inform the Form to exclude those extra fields.

Not sure how this will behave given a required field being excluded...

Answer (score 14):

Setting `self.exclude` does as @steve-pike mentions, make the whole `SubSectionAdmin` singleton change its exclude property.
A singleton is a class that will reuse the same instance every time the class is instantiated, so an instance is only created on the first use of the constructor, and subsequent use of the constructor will return the same instance. See the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) for a more indept description.
This means that if you write code to exclude the field on change it will have the implication that if you first add an item, the field will be there, but if you open an item for change, the field will be excluded for your following visits to the add page.

The simplest way to achieve a per request behaviour, is to use `get_fields` and test on the `obj` argument, which is `None` if we are adding an object, and an instance of an object if we are changing an object. The `get_fields` method is available from Django 1.7.

```
class SubSectionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        fields = super(SubSectionAdmin, self).get_fields(request, obj)
        if obj:  # obj will be None on the add page, and something on change pages
            fields.remove('field')
        return fields
```

**Update:**

Please note that `get_fields` may return a tuple, so you may need to convert `fields` into a list to remove elements.
You may also encounter an error if the field name you try to remove is not in the list. Therefore it may, in some cases where you have other factors that exclude fields, be better to build a set of excludes and remove using a list comprehension:

```
class SubSectionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        fields = list(super(SubSectionAdmin, self).get_fields(request, obj))
        exclude_set = set()
        if obj:  # obj will be None on the add page, and something on change pages
            exclude_set.add('field')
        return [f for f in fields if f not in exclude_set]
```

Alternatively you can also make a `deepcopy` of the result in the `get_fieldsets` method, which in other use cases may give you access to better context for excluding stuff. Most obviously this will be useful if you need to act on the fieldset name. Also, **this is the only way to go if you actually use fieldsets** since that will omit the call to `get_fields`.

```
from copy import deepcopy

class SubSectionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_fieldsets(self, request, obj=None):
        """Custom override to exclude fields"""
        fieldsets = deepcopy(super(SubSectionAdmin, self).get_fieldsets(request, obj))

        # Append excludes here instead of using self.exclude.
        # When fieldsets are defined for the user admin, so self.exclude is ignored.
        exclude = ()

        if not request.user.is_superuser:
            exclude += ('accepted_error_margin_alert', 'accepted_error_margin_warning')

        # Iterate fieldsets
        for fieldset in fieldsets:
            fieldset_fields = fieldset[1]['fields']

            # Remove excluded fields from the fieldset
            for exclude_field in exclude:
                if exclude_field in fieldset_fields:
                    fieldset_fields = tuple(field for field in fieldset_fields if field != exclude_field)  # Filter
                    fieldset[1]['fields'] = fieldset_fields  # Store new tuple

        return fieldsets
```

Answer (score 1):

The approach below has the advantage of not overriding the object wide `exclude` property; instead it is reset based on each type of request

```
class SubSectionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    add_exclude = ('field1', 'field2')
    edit_exclude = ('field2',)

    def add_view(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.exclude = getattr(self, 'add_exclude', ())
        return super(SubSectionAdmin, self).add_view(*args, **kwargs)

    def change_view(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.exclude = getattr(self, 'edit_exclude', ())
        return super(SubSectionAdmin, self).change_view(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: ModelAdmin classes are singletons, so modifying their state is problematic

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can override `get_fieldsets` method of `ModeAdmin` class. See the example below, in the code example below, I only want to display `country` field in the form when adding a new country, In order to check if object is being added, we simply need to check if `obj == None`, I am specifying the fields I need. Now otherwise `obj != None` means existing object is being changed, so you can specify which fields you want to exclude from the change form.

```
def get_fieldsets(self, request: HttpRequest, obj=None):
    fieldset = super().get_fieldsets(request, obj=obj)
    if obj == None: # obj is None when you are adding new object.
        fieldset[0][1]["fields"] = ["country"]
    else:
        fieldset[0][1]["fields"] = [
            f.name
            for f in self.model._meta.fields
            if f.name not in ["id", "country"]
        ]
    return fieldset
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override the `get_exclude` method of the admin.ModelAdmin class:

```
    def get_exclude(self, request, obj):
        if "change" in request.path.split("/"):
            return [
                "fields",
                "to",
                "exclude",
            ]

        return super().get_exclude(request, obj)
```

I think this is cleaner than the provided answers. It doesn't override the `exclude` field of the Class explicitly, but rather only contextually provides the fields you wish to exclude depending on what view you're on.