# Dynamic forms in django-admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-forms

I want to make admin add-form dynamic. I want to add few formfields depending on setting in related object.

I have something like this:

```
class ClassifiedsAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):


  def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
     super(ClassifiedsAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
     self.fields['testujemy'] = forms.CharField(label = "test")
```

And in admin.py:

```
class ClassifiedAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
         return ClassifiedsAdminForm
```

As you can see, I want to add "testujemy" CharField to admin add-form and change-form. However, this way doesnt work. Is there any way to add field in **init**? It is working in normal view.

Answer (score 8):

I've managed to do it using type().

```
class ClassifiedAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

 def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):

    adminform = ClassifiedsAdminForm()
    fields = adminform.getNewFields()

    form = type('ClassifiedsAdminForm', (forms.ModelForm,), fields)

    return form
```

Hope it will help someone.

Comment: Thanks, great work, saved me a lot of time figuring it out myself :)

Comment: This still greatly confuses me.  I would expect to be able to simply specify the form class in the ModelAdmin class definition.  I appreciate your adding this answer, though; there are a couple other SO questions that seem equivalent but remain un- or incompletely answered.

Comment: If this doesn't make sense to you, read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python   until it does.  Django uses metaclasses heavily internally, particularly with Models and Forms