# How do I create a custom UserChangeForm that does not allow certain fields to be edited?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-forms

This is my second post on SO, as well as my second post on Django--please be gentle.

I am working on a simple User model. Users should be able to sign up for the site, and after signing up they should be able to change their account settings upon login. However, if I do the following, Users see a huge form with all kinds of info I don't want them to edit:

## views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, get_object_or_404
from django.core import urlresolvers
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserChangeForm

@login_required 
def settings( request, template_name = 'accounts/settings.html' ):
    """
    Processes requests for the settings page, where users
    can edit their profiles.
    """
    page_title = 'Account Settings'
    if request.method == 'POST':
        postdata = request.POST.copy()
        form = UserChangeForm( postdata )
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    else:
        form = UserChangeForm()
    title = 'Settings'
    return render_to_response( template_name, locals(), context_instance = RequestContext( request) )
```

As if that wasn't bad enough, this form doesn't allow any changes to be made, citing "User with this Username already exists" as an error. This confuses me--I am attempting to save a UserChangeForm, so wouldn't it already existing be a given?

I've been looking online for a while now, attempting making my own custom forms, based on [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866896/django-admin-remove-field-if-editing-an-object) I've seen on SO, like so:

## forms.py

```
class CustomUserChangeForm( UserChangeForm ):
    def __init__( self, *args, **kwargs ):
        super( CustomUserChangeForm, self ).__init__( *args, **kwargs )
        if self.instance and self.instance.pk:
            # Since the pk is set this is not a new instance
            self.fields['username'] = self.instance.username
            self.fields['username'].widgets.attrs['readonly'] = True
```

Unfortunately this hasn't worked out. I'm kind of at a loss as to what to do, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Below are my urls.py and template:

## urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('appname.accounts.views',

    url(r'^settings/$', 'settings', { 
            'template_name': 'accounts/settings.html' 
        }, 'settings'
    ),
)
```

## template

```
{% extends "accounts/base.html" %}

{% block main %}
    <h1>Welcome, {{ request.user.pk }}{{ request.user.username }} to accounts.templates.accounts.settings.html.</h1>
    <h2>Here you can update your user settings. You can change your password <a href="{% url change_password %}">here</a>.</h2>
    <form action="." method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <p><input type="submit" value="Update &rarr;"></p>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First: to limit which fields are in the form, follow the [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#using-a-subset-of-fields-on-the-form). There are basically two options to filter fields: `fields` and `exclude`.

Second: you are always creating a new user. Initialize form with the User instance, not only you will be able to save a form, but you will have an initial data set.

Your view code should read:

```
# in the POST:
form = UserChangeForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)

# otherwise
form = UserChangeForm(instance=request.user)
```

and remove value assignment from the `form.py`.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I should have checked the documentation more thoroughly, sorry about that. As per your suggestions I changed the form to take an instance of User.

However, it seems like when inheriting UserChangeForm, I can't `exclude` User.username. Regardless of whether I set fields in the Meta, or exclude it specifically, the username field shows up on the form. I am wondering whether it might have something to do with [this ticket](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/8620). Your thoughts?

Comment: I've got same issue some time ago... it looks like first `Meta` class definitions in the class-chain is kept without override

Comment: That doesn't seem to be true. I found out you apparently can't exclude `username` and `password` neither through `exclude` nor `fields`.
Any Ideas on how to achieve that?

Comment: You can't exclude fields for UserChangeForm

Answer (score 5):

I think I'm pretty late on this one, but still I will post my bits for the sake of future readers.

```
class UserUpdateForm(UserChangeForm):
    password = None

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'description', ]
        widgets = {
            'description': forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows': 3}),
            'username': forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly': 'readonly'}),
            'email': forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly': 'readonly'})
        }
```

This will create a custom form with `username` and `email` fields as readonly as you do not want your users to change these unique fields once the user account has been created. It also prevents the `password` field to be displayed as it does not make sense to show hased `password` on  profile page.

Answer (score 4):

Three things. First of all, you should set self.fields['username'] to a form field, like forms.CharField(initial=self.instance.username). Second of all, you're using UserChangeForm instead of CustomUserChangeForm, in your view. And thirdly, http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#using-a-subset-of-fields-on-the-form (a proper link now, not one to someone's hard drive...

Answer (score 4):

This needs to be updated: You **cannot** exclude fields in UserChangeForm()

Too bad.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have not read the documentation carefully.

Let me help you with that, check out [using-a-subset-of-fields-on-the-form](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#using-a-subset-of-fields-on-the-form).

Basically you just need to add `exclude = ('fieldname',)` to your modelforms meta.

Comment: I'm really embarrassed that I missed docs that specifically address my question--thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The way it worked for me was to add a form class (in forms.py) overriding the UserChangeForm:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserChangeForm    

class UserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
"""Overriding visible fields."""
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'password', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name',)
```

Finally import this version on views.py instead of the contrib.auth.forms

Answer (score 1):

I also was facing a problem to exclude the password field and that's how I landed here.

And after checking code of some good projects I found a way to exclude the password field (without using exclude)

Just put `password = None` like shown in the code below.

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserChangeForm    

class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):

    # make the password as None for removing the password field from the form
    password = None

    class Meta:
        model = User

        # select the fields that you want to display
        fields = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name',)
```