# Exclude a field in django admin for users not super admin

Tags: django, django-admin, django-forms

how i'll exclude a field in django admin if the users are not super admin?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did it in this way:

## admin.py

```
def add_view(self, request, form_url='', extra_context=None):  
        if not request.user.is_superuser:     
            self.exclude=('activa', )        
        return super(NoticiaAdmin, self).add_view(request, form_url='', extra_context=None)
```

Comment: but i need to repeat with the change_view too :(, somebody have another method?
thanks

Comment: You can't do the same for `change_view`?

Comment: all fine, i did it, just i would like to know if there is another way :)

Comment: Changing self.exclude effects all following requests.

Answer (score 3):

Overriding the exclude property is a little dangerous unless you remember to set it back for other permissions, a better way might be to override the `get_form` method.

see: [Django admin: exclude field on change form only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245214/django-admin-exclude-field-on-change-form-only/6374206#6374206)

Answer (score 1):

In the future, it looks like there will be a get_fields hook.  But it's only in the master branch, not 1.5 or 1.6.

```
def get_fields(self, request, obj=None):
    """
    Hook for specifying fields.
    """
    return self.fields
```

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/options.py

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of views, you can use this decorator :

```
def exclude(fields=(), permission=None):
    """
        Exclude fields in django admin with decorator
    """
    def _dec(func):
        def view(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            if not request.user.has_perm(permission):
                self.exclude=fields
            return func(self, request, *args, **kwargs)
        return view
    return _dec
```

usage:
@exclude(fields=('fonction', 'fonction_ar'))